# convert linux python multiprocessing to windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, multiprocessing

I would like to use this Linux Python script in Windows Python.

how to rewrite it ? The part to be rewritten in multiprocessing part.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from collections import Counter
import glob
import multiprocessing
import os
import re
import sys
import time

def create_data(filepath):
    ...
    return values

filepaths = glob.glob('*/*.txt')
num_tasks = len(filepaths)

p = multiprocessing.Pool()
results = p.imap(create_data, filepaths)
while (True):
    completed = results._index
    print("\r--- Completed {:,} out of {:,}".format(completed, num_tasks), end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
    if (completed == num_tasks): break
p.close()
p.join()
df_full = pd.DataFrame(list(results))
print()
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: Think about it. There's no `fork`, so the script has to be re-executed in each child process. It must do something to avoid recursively spawning processes. The multiprocessing module uses the obvious solution. Hint: What's in a `__name__`? That which we call a module,
by any other `__name__` would execute as well.